# Trigger a function after clicking on an image for 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an invisible button on my web that, when pressed for 3 seconds, I want it to do something.

So far I've tried this:

```js
$("#basicChn").on({
  mousedown: function() {
    $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
      launchBasicChannel();
    }, 3000));
  },
  mouseup: function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
  }
});

function launchBasicChannel() {
  tts.say("Basic channel has been launched");
}
```

```css
.recRojo {
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  top: -30px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="imagenes/index/Rectangulo.png" class="recRojo" alt="btnSecreto" id="basicChn">
```

However, it is not working. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: how can you click an invisible button

Comment: its hidden so how can anyone do action with it?

Comment: ... and if it is not hidden, it works fine as per your requirements.

Comment: The web page is to be displayed on a robot, the button was supposed to be a way for them to access the administration mode of said robot(they insisted there is no way a client would find it by accident). I assumed that, even if the button was invisible, if you know it's there it could be clicked since it is not "disabled".

Comment: @LuisFernandez does `$(".recRojo").click();` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could write it a little like this.

```js
// hold mouse on the hidden object for 3 seconds to launch
$("#hiddenImage").on("mousedown", function(e) {
    
    clearTimeout(this.downTimer); // clear the timer
    
    // start the timer for 3 seconds
    this.downTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        launchBasicChannel();
    }, 3000);
    
}).mouseup(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(this.downTimer); // clear the timer
});

function launchBasicChannel() {
  console.log("Basic channel has been launched");
}
```

```css
#hiddenImage {
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  top: -30px;
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hiddenImage"></div>
```